# How to store huge tile map?

Tags: java, sql, arrays, database, tile

I'm coding a Java tile based game, and I am interested in the best way to store a really big tile map in a database. (The entire map is divided into chunks.)

I can store tiles data as a 2D array, or an array of strings (for each chunk), e.g.:

```
["1100111223333",
 "3130111213333",
 "1300311233333",
 .............................]
```

where each number represents a concrete tile.

This approach is the easiest, but when I use a really big map such as **20000x20000** tiles, it takes an indecent lot of memory!

According to my calculations: if the array is 20000x20000 and each tile uses 3 bytes
(I don't know exactly how much space a character in a string uses) then 20000*20000*3 = 1200000000 bytes or **1.14GB**!

That's too much space I think.

Maybe I can also store data in the form of:

```
["G18W3S23G12W3",
["W13G3S5G12W3",
.................................]
```

which means 18 tiles of Grass then 3 tiles of Water then 2 tiles of Sand and so on...

But I think it's a bad approach.

Probably I can create images for every chunk and get tiles from it, but it is quite difficult to use images in a database, isn't it?

So how can I do this most effectively?

**P.S:** I use an array of strings, because I have no idea how to create a 2d array in SQL (is it possible?)

Comment: Is your world randomly generated ? Because except with very small tiles I really wonder how you can design a prebuilt world of 20k*20k tiles. And if it's proceduraly generated, there are some better way to optimize world saving.

Comment: It's proceduraly generated (Perlin Noise)

Answer (score 3):

Because it's procedurally generated, you have a very good way to optimize your save files.
You can do the minecraft version: save your seed, so you don't have to save your whole map, and then save the tiles that were modified after generation of each chunk of the map.

Then when you load, generate the needed chunks based on your seed, and apply the  modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to load it all at once? You have divided it into chunks to not having to load everything, haven't you?

Answer (score 0):

The idea you have is already good. Compression would greatly reduce the size (even just run-length encoding like your example, but other algorithms like zip even more). If you already divided the data into chunks, then just compress each one seperately and decompress it on the fly when you load (and you won't load all that data at once, will you). Will the chunks change? If not, you could just work on a plain zip file instead of a database. If they do change, then don't do that, zip files can't be changed easily.

Comment: Yes, maybe, but 8000x8000 map in png format weights less than 2MB. So there is some more effective algorithm

Comment: 64000000 characters in a small alphabet shouldn't be a big compressed textfile either. On the other hand, if you don't have problems with using an image format, then go for it (i personally would prefer parsing text over images, but that's a matter of taste)

Comment: @user3696488: apples and oranges. PNG uses *two* optimizations: a Line Difference filter ([PNG Spec: 6. Filter Algorithms](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-Filters.html)), which makes things (even) more compressible for [LZW compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Welch).

Answer (score 0):

might sound to simple, but you can use compression! (and it might be too late already, hahhaaa)

if you know how Huffman compression works (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) you'll find your storage might shrink enormously...

and once you know that Java CAN ALREADY do this for you, here is my simple approach...

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;


public class Abc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Abc().doIt();
    }

    private void doIt() {

        try {
            //create a big Object (well my string might not be big)
            String veryBigObject = new String("have a class that implements serializable, like String") ;
            File file = new File("myFile.bin");

            //write it as zipped stream into a file
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file) ) );
            oos.writeObject(veryBigObject);
            oos.close();

            //read it back again
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(file) ) );
            String loadedInstance = (String)ois.readObject();
            ois.close();
            System.out.println(loadedInstance);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

then this is the output:

```
have a class that implements serializable, like String
```

i hope i'm not too late at all